# Why is it necessary to rationalize the denominator in complex division? (non-polar form)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I haven't been able to understand why the division algorithm requires this, (my high school textbook says that the division algorithm **only** works with natural numbers in the denominator), while rationalized answers in algebra after high school are not a requirement, I still don't get why I can't find a way to do the complex division without rationalizing the denominator and getting the imaginary part out of the denominator. Thanks for you help.

PD: I'm ignoring the polar form division because it's not in my textbook.

Comment: You mean the denominator? I haven't seen people purposely make the numerator real in complex division

Comment: @Triatticus Yes, sorry, the lack of sleep is playing with me.

Comment: You don't know how to divide by $1+2$ if you only know how to divide by $1$ and $2$.  Similarly you don't know how to divide by $1+i$, but you know how to multiply by $\frac{1-i}2$, which is the same thing.

Comment: Because it makes it easier?

Comment: @MattSamuel So this is not something special about complex numbers? Would I have the same problem while trying to do division with a root in the numerator? I'm confused because most people in here say that rationalization is not actually necessary, so I thought there was something special with complex numbers. Thanks.

Comment: @Travis I know very well that it's easier, what I'm asking is if its _completely necessary_.

Comment: @NickCassol I'm not 100% positive, but I don't think so, you can multiply complex numbers, so why would you not be able to divide with them in the denominator?

Comment: I suppose the real reason you need to is because the method you're using requires you to do it, not because it's impossible to do it otherwise.

Comment: An example might help. Do you just mean why we divide, say, $5 + 6i$ by $2 - i$ by writing as a fraction and rationalizing the denominator? Or why we don't just leave the fraction as $\frac{5+6i}{2-i}$, but instead find another way to write it?

Comment: The one thing to think is, how will you simplify a complex fraction into the form of $a+bi$ if you can't make the denominator a single number

Comment: @Nick "necessary" is relative. It's necessary if you want the answer to be in the form $a+bi$. If you don't care what form the answer is in then you can just leave it, because it is a valid way to write the number.

Comment: @pjs36 what I'm trying to say is that to me, this way of division seems a little bit "hacky", but the way it makes things so much easier makes me question why is it that we cannot divide two complex numbers easily without rationalizing. Therefore, I'm asking if its **completely necessary** to do this, or it's just that this is the easiest way to do it with high school algebra.

Comment: @MattSamuel Ah, got it, so it's just a matter of form?

Comment: @Nick Yes. And whether the form matters depends on what you're trying to do. $\frac63$ is the same thing as $2$, but only $2$ is suitable for some purposes.

Comment: @NickCassol It is not **completely necessary** (btw, calling it "*rationalizing*" is not the best choice of words), but it makes calculations easier. Taking an example posted in a previous comment, $\frac{5+6i}{2-i}=\frac{(5+6i)(2+i)}{2^2+1^2}=\frac{4+17i}{5}=\frac{4}{5} + i\frac{17}{5}\,$. You could, instead, write $\frac{5+6i}{2-i}=a+bi\,$ then solve the system $5=2a+b, 6=2b-a$ for $a,b$ with the same result, only some more work.